# Snappoint with eyeshot

Tags: eyeshot

I have make snap point to my application, but it make my application slowdown, some one can help me?

My application is drawing like autocad drafting, and I am using eyeshot SDK to develop it.

It looks like okay until I am using pan/rotate.

This is my code

```
public SnapPoint[] GetSnapPoints(System.Drawing.Point mouseLocation)
{
    // changed PickBoxSize to define a range for display snapPoints
    var oldSize = PickBoxSize;
    PickBoxSize = 10;

    var snapPoints = new List<SnapPoint>();
    var entityIndexs = GetAllEntitiesUnderMouseCursor(mouseLocation, false);

    if (entityIndexs.Length > 0)
    {
        var countindex = 0;

        foreach (int index in entityIndexs)
        {
            if (Entities[index] is ICurve entCurve)
            {
                var indexVerTex = 0;
                var endPoints = entCurve.GetPointsByLength(0.9);

                foreach (Point3D vertex in Entities[index].Vertices)
                {
                    snapPoints.Add(new SnapPoint(vertex, ObjectSnapType.End));

                    if (indexVerTex > 0)
                    {
                        var midPoint = FindMidPoint3D(Entities[index].Vertices[indexVerTex - 1], vertex);
                        snapPoints.Add(new SnapPoint(midPoint,ObjectSnapType.Mid));
                    }

                    indexVerTex++;
                }

                if (entCurve is LinearPath linearPath)
                {
                    var temptPoints = this.GetIntersectBySeft(linearPath);

                    if (temptPoints.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var temptPoint in temptPoints)
                        {
                            if (!CheckPointInSnapPoints(temptPoint, snapPoints))
                            {
                                snapPoints.Add(new SnapPoint(temptPoint, ObjectSnapType.Intersect));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (countindex > 0)
                {
                    Point3D intersectPoint3D = null;

                    if (Entities[entityIndexs[countindex - 1]] is ICurve line1 && Entities[entityIndexs[countindex]] is ICurve line2)
                    {
                        if (line1 is LinearPath linePath1)
                        {
                            var intersectPoints = linePath1.IntersectWith(line2);

                            foreach (Point3D intersectPoint in intersectPoints)
                            {
                                snapPoints.Add(new SnapPoint(intersectPoint, ObjectSnapType.Intersect));
                            }
                        }
                        else if (line2 is LinearPath linePath2)
                        {
                            var intersectPoints = linePath2.IntersectWith(line1);

                            foreach (Point3D intersectPoint in intersectPoints)
                            {
                                snapPoints.Add(new SnapPoint(intersectPoint, ObjectSnapType.Intersect));
                            }
                         }
                         else if (CompositeCurve.IntersectionLineLine(line1, line2, out intersectPoint3D))
                         {
                             snapPoints.Add(new SnapPoint(intersectPoint3D, ObjectSnapType.Intersect));
                         }
                     }
                 }

                 foreach (Point3D endPoint in endPoints)
                 {
                     if (!CheckPointInSnapPoints(endPoint, snapPoints))
                     {
                         snapPoints.Add(new SnapPoint(endPoint, ObjectSnapType.Nearest));
                     }
                 }
             }
               
             countindex++;
        }
    }

    var entIndex = GetEntityUnderMouseCursor(mouseLocation);
    Point3D tempPoint = null;
       
    if (entIndex > -1)
    {
    }

    var snaps = snapPoints.ToArray();

    return snaps;
}
```

And this

```
public List<Point3D> GetIntersectBySeft(LinearPath linearPath)
{
    var lines = linearPath.ConvertToLines();
    var temPoint3Ds = new List<Point3D>();

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+2; j < lines.Length; j++)
        {
            temPoint3Ds.AddRange(lines[i].IntersectWith(lines[j]));
        }
    }

    var tempPoints2 = new List<Point3D>();

    foreach (var temPoint in temPoint3Ds)
    {
        if (!tempPoints2.Contains(temPoint))
        {
            tempPoints2.Add(temPoint);
        }
    }

    return tempPoints2;
}
```

and this

```
public bool CheckPointInSnapPoints(Point3D point, List<SnapPoint> snapPoints)
{
    return snapPoints.Any(snapPoint => point.X == snapPoint.X && point.Y == snapPoint.Y);
}

public Point3D FindMidPoint3D(Point3D pointA, Point3D pointB)
{
    return new Point3D((pointA.X+pointB.X)/2,(pointA.Y+pointB.Y)/2);
}
```

Can anyone help me with this problem and optimize for best performance in this case, please?

Answer (score 0):

I build my SnapPoints in MouseMove Event with Labels. See pic.[Example Arc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MS2em.png) In MouseDown you can click the Labels. The Label.Anchorpoint is the Point you search for.

1. Give the MouseMoveEvent a Timer with 30ms for searching the SnapPoints.
2. You don't need any List. Generate just those SnapPoints for the EntityUnderMouseCursor and not for all

In MouseMove ( Line-Example )

If TypeOf EntityUnderMouse Is Line Then

```
            Dim Line1 As Line = DirectCast(et, Line)

            Model1.Labels.Add(New Labels.ImageOnly(Line1.StartPoint, GenerateLabelEndPoint(Color.Orange), 5, 5))
            Model1.Labels.Add(New Labels.ImageOnly(Line1.MidPoint, GenerateLabelCenterLine(Color.Yellow), 6, 6))
            Model1.Labels.Add(New Labels.ImageOnly(Line1.EndPoint, GenerateLabelEndPoint(Color.Orange), 5, 5))
```

Endif

In MouseDown you have just to click the Label und get the AnchorPoint.

Hope I can help.

Regards